# How to install packages from the -proposed pocket

Tags: apt, updates

Even if a newer version of a package is present in the `-proposed` pocket, doing

```
sudo apt install <PACKAGE>
```

will only try to install the version in the `-release` or `-updates` pocket. How do i make the installer pick the version in `-proposed`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume jammy (Ubuntu 22.04).

First you need to add `-proposed` to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

To do that:

- Open *Software & Updates*
- Select the *Developer Options* tab
- Check *Pre-released updates*
- Click the *Close* button followed by clicking the *Reload* button

Optionally you can edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` manually. Add a line similar to this:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-proposed multiverse restricted main universe
```

and run `sudo apt update` to refresh the package information on your system.

With `-proposed` enabled you can then do:

```
sudo apt install <PACKAGE>/jammy-proposed
```

i.e. you should tell the installer explicitly to install from the `-proposed` pocket.

### *Caution*

Once you have installed the package(s) from `-proposed`, remember to disable `-proposed` again. If you don't, `sudo apt upgrade` will update also a bunch of other packages but the one(s) you are interested in, and that's probably not what you want. (This behavior will change in Ubuntu 23.04, so packages in the `-proposed` pocket will have lower APT priority by default.)